# jQuery Show hide bugs out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I can't figure out why my more and less show function is messing with a show hide function. I have included a jsfiddle and a demo. It works one time good then screws up when i try to open it again. Press the top left img a couple time and you will see the issue. The text goes out of the div!

Jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/LLDLT/
DEMO:http://aucblock.x10.mx/eric/edited/

jQuery Code:

```
$("#e").click(function (e) {
    $("#u").hide(200);
    $("#n").hide(200);
    $("#l").hide(200);
    $("#a").hide(200);
    $("#m").hide(200);
    $(".eew").hide(200);
    $("#s").show(200);
    $("#re").animate({
        "margin-left": "0px"
    }, 200);
    $("#r").animate({
        "margin-left": "0px"
    }, 200);
    $("#s").animate({
        "margin-left": "2px"
    }, 200);
    $("#u").animate({
        "margin-left": "2px"
    }, 200);
    $("#n").animate({
        "margin-left": "2px"
    }, 200);
    $("#l").animate({
        "margin-left": "2px"
    }, 200);
    $("#a").animate({
        "margin-left": "2px"
    }, 200);
    $("#m").animate({
        "margin-left": "2px"
    }, 200);
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('body').on('click', '.highl', function () {
        if ($('#s').css('height') === '190px') {
            $('#s').animate({
                'height': '92px'
            }, 200);
            $(".highl").text("More");
            $(".eew").hide(200);
        } else {
            $('#s').animate({
                'height': '190px'
            }, 200);
            $(".highl").text("Less");
            $(".eew").css("display", "inline");
        }
    });
    $('body').on('click', '.tri', function () {
        $('#s').hide(200);
        $('.eew').hide();
        $('#s').animate({
            "height": "92px"
        }, 200);
    });
});
```

Comment: This hurts my eyes so much to look at

Comment: Sorry its a big question

Comment: Your `$('body').on('click'...` are wrapped inside your `$('#e').click(...` function. That's going to cause you some issues to start with.

Comment: For reference, you can group elements within a selector in jQuery just like you can in CSS: `$('#u, #n, #l, ...').hide(200);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you check out the inspector you will see that the parent div.popu has a definite height set at 92 pixels. The overflow text in the span will always appear outside of the background image in that scenario unless you allow the height to be "auto" or you add `overflow:scroll` to .popu